# Jumping effect on Mac OS X and iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

There is an animation when something gets done in Mac OS X. You know the animation on dock, when an icon is jumping.
Is there a way to do this on iPhone with a UIButton? If yes, please give me the start.
I know a way with cocos2D, but I think it can be done with core animations too.
Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this - [OS X Dock in an Iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885935/os-x-dock-in-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Ok, man. Thanks! But I want exactly the same jump. I can do a jump with coregraphics. I thought there is a way that is exactly the same as dock jump.

Comment: Anyway I accept this... Maybe later somebody will give me a better answer.

Comment: Here it is in the AppKit docs but not sure if you can port onto the iPhone... Look for NSRequestUserAttentionType http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html